# onClick not firing in React js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-router

I'm having troubles making this code work. When i click on the button, the component should re render and become a h1 tag. This code compiles, the problem is that when I click the button "Open Modal" nothing happens.

This is the last version i have.I'm fairly new to react.js so apologies in advance for my ignorance. Any ideas?

```
class AddTransactionForm extends React.Component {

      constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { modalActive: false };
        this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
      }

      openModal () {
        this.setState({ modalActive: true })
      }

      render () {
        if (this.state.modalActive){
          return(<h1>Active</h1>);
        }else{
          return (
                 <div>
                       <button className="button_" onClick={this.openModal}>Open modal</button>
                 </div>
        );
        }
    }
    }
```

Aditionaly, im getting this error in the console (although the error, the page renders and it's working fine)

Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./components/Transactions"
    at bundle.js:17
    at Object. (bundle.js:17)
    at t (bundle.js:1)
    at Object. (bundle.js:17)
    at t (bundle.js:1)
    at Object. (bundle.js:1)
    at t (bundle.js:1)
    at bundle.js:1
    at bundle.js:1

Comment: Have you checked by inspecting the html dom ?

Comment: Should work. Something else is broken.

Comment: Try wrapping your `<h1>` in a `<div>`.

Comment: @jmargolisvt why would that matter?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv where should i look for errors?

Comment: Try debugging this. Is `openModal` called at all? (do a `console.log('foo')` in it for starters and see if it's logged)

Comment: in your render method, I would add console.log(this.state.modalActive) just above your IF statement. Then use the developer tolls (typically F12 for chrome and IE) and watch the console output.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I addet the console.log in the openModal function, but it doesn't log anything out in the console. The onClick never fires the function.

Comment: How are you bundling your code? webpack? browserify? Enable source maps to get a clearer error message and see if fixing that doesn't help.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv yes, im using webpack. I'll try to track the error with source maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfectly fine. See the demo at http://codepen.io/umgupta/pen/dNPPXe
Looking at the error it seems like you are using a bundler. 
The issue might be that since the error might be throwing before the events bind, on click didn't bind.

```
class AddTransactionForm extends React.Component {

      constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { modalActive: false };
        this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
      }

      openModal () {
        this.setState({ modalActive: true })
      }

      render () {
        if (this.state.modalActive){
          return(<h1>Active</h1>);
        }else{
          return (
                 <div>
                       <button className="button_" onClick={this.openModal}>Open modal</button>
                 </div>
        );
        }
    }
    }


ReactDOM.render(
  <AddTransactionForm/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't know that i could test my components with this application. I'll try to track the error that was threw before